# Load several PostgreSQL tables to QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql

I have a list of datasets in a PostgreSQL DB and I need to load them all into a QGIS project. I am wondering if there is a way to load all of the desired tables into QGIS programmatically instead of having to add each manually.

I didn't know where to start, and after googling, I did not get any closer to a solution. I don't use Q, but need to prepare Q projects for others to use, and I need to create different ones with varying numbers of tables to load. Now, instead of having to tell everyone all of the tables to load and from which database, they just have to open the project.

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what you tried but before going through the programming, you could try selecting a range of layers in the "Data Source Manager" for your database.

Using a click to start with Shift key and clicking again later in the list select a range of tables/layers (PostGIS/QGIS perspectives)

[image: PostGIS Data Source Manager]

For a programming perspective, you can do the following:

```py
# Database manipulation from db connection name
from qgis.core import (
    QgsVectorLayer, QgsDataSourceUri,
    QgsProviderRegistry, QgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection
)

# Existing name already configured in the database manager
database_conn_name = 'The name in your connexion manager'
md = QgsProviderRegistry.instance().providerMetadata("postgres")
conn = md.createConnection(database_conn_name)

# List only tables with spatial
tables = conn.tables(flags=QgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection.Vector)

#list_tables_for_filtering = ['tablename_you_want_to_keep1', 'tablename_you_want_to_keep2']
#tables = [t for t in tables if t.defaultName() in list_tables_for_filtering]
for table in tables:
    tablename = table.defaultName()
    geometrycol = table.geometryColumn()
    schema = table.schema()
    conn_uri = conn.uri()
    print(tablename, geometrycol, schema, conn_uri)
    uri = QgsDataSourceUri(conn_uri)
    data_source_conf = [schema, tablename]
    if geometrycol:
        data_source_conf.append(geometrycol)
    else:
        data_source_conf.append(None)
    uri.setDataSource(*data_source_conf)
    vlayer=QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(False), tablename, "postgres")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vlayer)
```